# Python Selenium titles contain 'and' 'or' multiple conditions

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use selenium to filter multiple conditions, the idea is:
contains A or B or C, but any of A,B,C does not contain D and does not contain E or F

I use:

```
by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'A') or contains(@title,'B') or contains(@title,'C') and not(contains(@title,'D')) and not(contains(@title,'E') and not(contains(@title,'F'))]")]
```

But the results returning: A or B or C, but ignore the 'not contains' part.

Could you please help me with that? Thanks : ) !

Here's the specific website I use

```
driver.get('http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/zjfxzx/?tbnm=%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0&tc=null&isNewTab=1')
links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'公司债券') or contains(@title,'资产支持') or contains(@title,'金融债券') and not(contains(@title,'申购')) and not(contains(@title,'公告'))]")]
```

Comment: Can you show us HTML-sample for the same?

Comment: Hello Jason, please find my update question with website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like

```
//a[(contains(@title, 'A') or contains(@title, 'B') or contains(@title, 'C')) and not(contains(@title, 'D') or contains(@title, 'E') or contains(@title, 'F'))]
```

In your specific case

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[(contains(@title,'公司债券') or contains(@title,'资产支持') or contains(@title,'金融债券')) and not(contains(@title,'申购') or contains(@title,'公告'))]")]
```